# How to run a JPA Query in play Framework

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

I'm new to Play and also to hibernate and JPA.
I'm using MySql DB and JPA
I have included

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import play.db.jpa.JPA;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.db.jpa.*;
```

I have this Query

```
List languages = FormLanguages.findAll();
render(languages);
```

Which runs correctly, but i want to select based on id, something like this

"select * from FormLanguages where id>10"

When i use like this

```
Query query = JPA.em().createQuery("select * from FormLanguages");
List<FormLanguages> articles = query.getResultList();
render(articles);
```

Which gives me IllegalArgumentException error

When use like this

```
List queryList = FormLanguages.em().createQuery("select * from FormLanguages").getResultList();
render(queryList);
```

which gives the same error please help me how to write Query

Also suggest me some websites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your scenario:

```
List languages = FormLanguages.find("id > ?",10).fetch();
```

Should work.

[This one](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html) and also [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_overview_query.html) may help you learn the JPA query language. Once you are familiar with them, using `find` you can launch those queries. Or use [named queries](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28221/ent30qry001.htm).

Comment: I saw your links that was useful but can you suggest me links for Play Framework+Hibernate+JPA examples

Comment: The documentation has sone info, check this(http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/model) and this (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/jpa)